# Show Line Breaks in Stripe Email Description

Tags: php, email, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble showing line breaks in Stripe's email receipts. The email description is generated via PHP and `<br>`, `\r\n` are displayed literally. [image]

I also tried `nl2br` but since that displays `<br>` I'm sure it won't work.

**PHP**

```
$detail = "$name\r\n";
$detail .= "Length: $length,";
$detail .= " Width: $width,";
$detail .= "Color: $color,";
$detail .= "Qty: $qty\r\n";
$detail .= "Price: $price\r\n";

echo nl2br($detail);
```

**How can I display line breaks on my Stripe email receipt using PHP?**

Comment: Trying just using `\n`?  And why are you doing `nl2br`, since as you say it converts newlines to breaks?

Comment: yes i tried that. i said that so u know what i tried.

Comment: No, you said you tried `\r\n`

Comment: I said I tried nl2br so you know that I tried that(nl2br).

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this. Did you have any success?

Comment: @CharlieS I had no success. I'm using commas to separate everything. It's the best I could come up with for now.

Comment: I'll post my thoughts in an answer. I spoke with their support and have a little bit to share.

Comment: @CharlieS Yes please that would be great.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** It looks like Stripe began supporting line breaks at some point over the past few years, see comments on this answer.

---

**Previous answer:**

I was trying to achieve the same thing and ended up talking with their support. In short:

- HTML tags will always be converted to entities.
- `\n` will be ignored.

As I see it, you have 3 options within these current constraints:

1. Use commas (or whatever) for items on one long line:

   ```
   Shampoo - $5.00, Toothbrush - $2.00, Soap - $3.00 --------------- $10.00
   ```
2. Send your own email.
3. [Create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) in Stripe, then [create as many invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) as you need, then [create an invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice), then [pay the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice).

This does give you an invoice + a receipt email like this:

```
 Shampoo ----- $5.00
 Toothbrush -- $2.00
 Soap -------- $3.00

 Total ------ $10.00
```

**But there's 1 huge caveat to #3.** Invoices are automatically created by Stripe for all outstanding invoice items and subscription plans that a customer might have. This occurs 1 hour before an invoice should be charged (this is according to the interval that you might have setup for a plan, or perhaps at the end of the month if you're only dealing with invoice items, I'm not sure in the latter case.). This means you could technically have a customer checking out that gets charged for more items within the current transaction then they were anticipating, which just smells of bad design and a bad solution to a simple problem.

So, I'm sticking with comma separated items on 1 line for a current project, and doing custom emails whenever a client has the budget for us to build them.

Comment: Great, comprehensive answer - deserves more upvotes!

Comment: I just discovered that you can modify the charge description in the dashboard and it preserves newlines. So I made a test charge via the API and it seems that somewhere between 2014 and 2018, Stripe have changed this behaviour somewhat - newlines are now preserved! :)

Comment: I can also confirm it now accepts \n or <br> to create line breaks in the charge description.